# 2014 Chevy Impala Oil Sensor Location (P055b Engine oil pressure sensor/switch B - circuit range/performance)

Tags: chevrolet, impala, ecotec, oil-pressure-sensor

My 2014 Impala LS (2.5L Ecotec) is throwing an OBDII code for P055b. Immediately checked oil level with dipstick, all is fine there. I'm assuming that the sensor/switch (whichever it is) has simply failed. Problem is, I don't know precisely where it is. Considering that sensor "B" is failing, I'd think that sensor "A" also exists. I can see what I think is one, right on top of the engine by the intake solenoid (circled in red). But, I've not been able to find the other. Is this sensor B? If not, does anyone know where on the engine it is?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thank you! Hoping the community can help me out, and vice versa. :)

Comment: RockAuto.com is only showing one sensor (though it could be used two times). It should [look like this](https://www.rockauto.com/info/321/12661808_Primary__ra_p.jpg). I'm not sure where it would be at on the engine, though. Looking at the trouble code online, it suggest getting a pressure reading directly from the port, though it doesn't give a diagnosis as to what the issue is after the fact if you get a good oil pressure reading.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the 'b' at the end of the code does not indicate this is the "B" sensor, but rather just the trouble code itself. There's also a P055c code, but no P055a as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi so my 2014 chevy malibu is giving me the same codes P055c P055b did replacing these sensors solve the issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: It worked for about three months. I've been driving for over a year now with the code intermittently coming on and off. At this point, I've chalked it up to a wiring issue. From where I've read online, most people recommend fixing it with an aftermarket sensor that has looser tolerances (not GM's factory part). I've had no major issues with the car's oil system or performance yet.

Comment: I just replaced the sensor again (2nd time) about three weeks ago. Holding up so far. Got the AC Delco part with the two year warranty, will plan to use said warranty if it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the LKW engine P055B "Intake Camshaft Position Actuator Oil Pressure Sensor Performance" refers to the cylinder head oil pressure sensor. Circled in your picture. The engine oil pressure sensor is located on the block under the intake manifold. Up and right from the oil level switch shown in the picture.

Comment: Ended up taking it to my local shop to be safe, they determined the same. Thanks, shame I wasn't patient enough for your answer. XD